# admob ads on android tv

Tags: android, admob, android-tv

I'm planning to launch an app for Android TV 
and the monetization scheme would ideally be ads + in app purchases.

However I haven't seen any official statement whether admob ads are
allowed on Android TV or not.

Anyone can reference any official statement or personal experience?

Ps: Maybe [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953648/eric-leichtenschlag) can give us a more precise answer.

Comment: There's a similar discussion [Admob for Android TV app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892657/admob-for-android-tv-app) and @jose-gómez commented that it seems official support is not yet: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/C2Zy1alvbDU/yKkz7dMmKnQJ.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have read that. But the thread was active in March '15, So I hoped some more updated answer would be best.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also interested in update too. It is sad that Android TV still doesn't have standard advertising platform.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be allowed too?

However, you will need to keep in mind that Android TV does not have a web browsing component.  This means that certain types of advertising in your app will not be initially possible, while others will.

You will need to have interstitial and video ads that require no user interaction can be kept in your app, and you can't have adss that ask the user to follow a link to the we, or ask the user to install an app or game from the Play Store, as those apps/games may not be discoverable or operable.

Comment: Yes I agree on video ads. There is an option on admob interstitial to allow only video ads right?

Comment: What control do I have over admob ads besides setting the desired ad format (text, banner, video) ?