# Can Admob be integrated in Android TV

Tags: admob, android-tv

I have an Android app that supports both Mobile phones and Android TV. On few different blog discussions i heard some of devs got their Admob accounts banned for putting Ads in TV app. So i have **two questions** in this regard:

1. Since my App supports both mediums (TV & Phone), if i put Ads for Phone App only and doesn't show them on TV , Will that harm my Play or Admob account in any way?

   2.Can we put Ads in our TV APP ? Otherwise how do we monetize ?

**P.S**: I know this question has been asked before long ago, I couldn't find any fresh questions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can integrate Admob in Android TV. Make sure that your implementation should be compliant to the Admob policy.

Follow below question link for more details:
[Admob for Android TV app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892657/admob-for-android-tv-app)

Comment: But there's no official support of Admob for TV, is there any ?